# How to make a foreach button in vba that saves values for an array of textboxes?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have an List in a different form , and the values that are located inside the text boxes are retrieved from a list in a different form , my problem is that i cannot delete the values all at once because they come from a view and i'm not allowed to change multiple tables all at once, so my solution is to create an array with all my text boxes and to turn the value to null 1 by 1 and save them individual so that i don't get that error.

I've tried different solutions like saving everything at once.

```vb
Private Sub Comando28_Click()
Dim strTextBoxes(1 To 5) As String

tbAplic = Me.TbUAplicacion.Value

tbUsr = Me.tbuUsuario.Value

tbMail = Me.tbuMailUsuario.Value

tbnmbre = Me.tbuNombrePersona.Value

tbAppld = Me.tbuApellidosPersona.Value

tbDni = Me.tbuDNIPersona.Value

Dim ITM As strTextBoxes.ITM

For Each ITM In strTextBoxes.ITM
    If ITM = Not Null Then ITM = Null
    Guardar_Click '<---- this is a macro which I use to save the items new value
Next ITM

End Sub
```

the error it gives me when pressing the button that should make the action is as follows:

the user-defined type has not been defined

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Private Sub Comando28_Click()

    Dim strTextBoxes(1 To 5) As String

    tbAplic = Me.TbUAplicacion.Value

    tbUsr = Me.tbuUsuario.Value

    tbMail = Me.tbuMailUsuario.Value

    tbnmbre = Me.tbuNombrePersona.Value

    tbAppld = Me.tbuApellidosPersona.Value

    tbDni = Me.tbuDNIPersona.Value

    Dim ITM As String
    Dim Item As Long

    For Item = LBound(strTextBoxes) To UBound(strTextBoxes)
        ITM = strTextBoxes(Item)
        If ITM <> "" Then ITM = ""
        Guardar_Click '<---- this is a macro which I use to save the items new value
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: it did not work , it simply does nothing it does not change the values in any text box

Comment: Neither would your original code do, but now you have no error. We have no idea how it should work with the "Guardar_Click" macro. If you wish to clear the textboxes listed, just set their Value to _Null_.